# Brand new MacBook Pro touch bar F4 trouble

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

Just a couple of days into owning a new MacBook Pro (14,3) It seems the f4 key doesn't work if iTunes is open - I searched a bit and people were having this issue in January - Is there a fix / workaround (other than quitting iTunes) ?

It disables f4 on external keyboards too, and takes approx. 30 seconds after iTunes has quit to function correctly again.

100 % reproducible - can't imagine that this has been left unsolved for this many months.
any ideas ?
thanks !

Comment: I just noticed this issue also - vim no longer able to receive F4. Shift F4 still works. It started when I launched iTunes. It's issue 30234592 titled "iTunes stops F4 key from working on 2016 MBP with TouchBar". However I could not get access to this find out more... Same happens with Spotify and other apps - so it's not just iTunes